# Every Deployment on ECS using AWS Codepipeline creates a new version of task definition

Tags: amazon-ecs

Every time a deployment happens, Codepipeline creates a new version of the task definition. How do I avoid it?

I want to specifically use a particular version.

Comment: Hey Reyansh, are you using a ECS deploy stage in your CodePipeline, right? That's exactly how it's supposed to work, everytime you create a new Docker image, it'll create a new task definition revision and that's how it replaces the old one. Why would you need to use always the same revision if you're (I guess) triggering the pipeline to update the Docker image? or what's your use case here? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm using ECS deploy which is triggered when the latest image is pushed to ECR. I wanted to modify my task definition. I thought it would be better if I could modify the same task definition and let the ECS deploy create new revisions from the modified task definition.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Modifying a task definition means creating a new revision actually. So, you'll be doing exactly the same as CodeDeploy would do to deploy that new/updated task definition.

Comment: But codedeploy just seems to take into account the image for creating revision. Let's say I modify the task definition to use a mount point. The subsequent revision isn't launched with the added mount point.

Comment: What do you suggest I go with if I need to make modifications for task definition in terms of mount points, storage, or entrypoint. Should I be creating a new task definition and update the service to use new task definition?

Comment: Any edition you need to do (being Docker image, mount point, storage, anything) will require a new task definition revision. Revisions are "frozen" configuration files, which can be used to cherrypick anyone you'd eventually need. So yes, you'll need to create a new revision every time you update any resource of that definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206722/discussion-between-reyansh-kharga-and-marianogg9).